# Crystal Report having In Memory Data Set with two related tables

Tags: crystal-reports

I have to create Report in Crystal Report from In memory data set.

This data set have two tables.

1st table is base table "ReportBase" having following fields

ReportID [PK]

ReportType

Second Table is "StudentReport" which has

ReportID [FK]

StudentName

Address

In Report I want to display fields from both tables.

Please suggest me any article or sample code. Remember Data is not comming from any database. i have to fill data tables from in memory data.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Export your "In-memory" data to comma-delimited text files.

Step 2: Import these text files into Crystal.